# Selected group not visible in admin panel

Tags: django-admin, user-permissions

Iam using Django 2.2.5.
Create user using django model form in my template(There is a Choice field named group )
I extend the Group model to BaseUser and assign some permissions(For creating and assinging permission I choose django admin panel)

**Problem :** Selected group are not visible in the admin panel when create a user from my template, but when I looking to the model selected group was visible in the group field.

So Ican't manage my template based on the group permission. Otherwise I need to assign permission again using my admin panel
How can I solve this problem. Help me please.
Thank you.

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import User


    class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
        fieldsets = (
            (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password', 'name', 'last_login', 'user_code')}),
            ('Permissions', {'fields': (
                'is_active', 
                'is_staff', 
                'is_superuser', 
                'groups', 
                'user_permissions',
            )}),
            )
    
        add_fieldsets = (
            (
                None,
                {
                    'classes':('wide',),
                    'fields':('email', 'password1', 'password2')
                }
            ),
        )
        
        list_display = ('email', 'name', 'is_staff', 'last_login')
        list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
        search_fields = ('email',)
        ordering = ('email',)
        filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
        
                    
    admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

User/models.py

```
group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = '+')
```

My model image

[image]

My admin panel image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean it does not display in the user Change view then try this:

`class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

## your other stuff

list_display = ('email', 'name', 'is_staff', 'last_login', 'get_groups')

## your other stuff

def get_groups(self, obj):
return ", ".join([group.name for group in obj.groups.all()])`